# Can we Sync the "Contact Information" section inside the users' my-site from active directory

Tags: 2013, user-profile, user-profile-service, active-directory, active-directory-import

I have accessed some my-sites for our users, and i find that each site have a section named "Contact Information" as follow:-

[image]

so i have these questions regarding the above:-

1) can we sync all these info or part of these info from active directory ?

2) now if users enter these info manually, and later on we manage to populate these info from active directory, then will the data entered by the users get overridden ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. That is the purpose of the User Profile Synchronization Service. You need to configure the Import field mapping from AD to the User Profile. This is done in the User Profile Service Application | User Profile Property settings. Choose each property, select the AD field you wish to import from. This will cause the existing data to be overwritten by the AD values.

Comment: so you mean all these info can be synced from AD ? now currently the user profile sync service is stopped, so there is not sync with AD.. so can u advice on these 2 questions accordingly please. 1) if i keep the sync service stopped , then users will manually enter the info such as mobile,fax, home phone, etc , but what if we chose to start the sync later on, will the info inside the AD override the data entered by the users?

Comment: ..second question , now if we configure the sync to work from the beginning, then will the users still be able to modify these values (mobile phone, fax, etcc)? or if we start the user profile sync service , then these fields will be disabled , since they are just representing what is inside AD? thanks for your help on this..

Comment: First, you have to separate User Profile Service from the Synchronization Service, they are two separate things. You should be running sync so that newly added users to AD are added to User Profiles. You have to decide if you want the properties to come from AD to SP (import), reside in SP alone (no sync), or flow from SP to AD (export). The import will always overwrite the data, so don't let users edit info that you import.

Comment: So the base line here is that if i chose to import the user profile info from AD, then all users data inside the contact info (such as mobile phone, fax, etc..) will be override ? is that correct ? second point which i can not get my head around it,, now if i start the AD-Import and i configure it to run daily.. then will the "Contact Info" fields such as Mobile phone, Fax, etc... get disabled automatically ? or these field will still be editable by users but their values will get overriden on the next User Profile sync schedule run?

Comment: Yes it will be overwritten. No, the fields will not be disabled, you need to do that at the property level yourself.

Comment: thanks for the info  and help... now i checked the fields inside the My-Sites and in our case some fields such as Fax, Mobile, home phone are already inside AD. but other fields such as Assistant are not inside AD.. so can we have a hybrid appraoch where some values will be pushed from AD such as fax, mobile and home phone,, while other values such as Assistant to be entered by the user in sharepoint  ??are things flexible ?

Comment: Yes, they are flexible.